# Comment utiliser "que" ou "quoi" dans une question ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, questions

I have already read the other questions and I don't seem to find the answer to my doubt.
I don't know when it is wrong to use "quoi" instead of "que" in a French question

Comment: Welcome! Maybe try to provide an example question. How is it different from those you've read in the questions you mentioned. You can also link to such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, read that https://www.thoughtco.com/what-in-french-1369498 .if you need precision, ask me.

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?